# understanding code to print 123456789987654321 by recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

Okay, i'm reading book jumping into c++ and i've made it to chapter 16 successfully which is about recursion. I read the chapter and watched few youtube videos so i guess i know how they work. But when i tried to understand this code given in book, i failed.
According to my understanding this code **should print 1234567899**. I have commented the lines/section which im unable to understand.
Please be very descriptive when explaining as I want to clear my doubts completely.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printNum (int num)
{

    cout << num ;

    if ( num < 9 )
    {
        printNum( num + 1 ); //if statement should continue untill 123456789 prints on screen
    }
    cout << num; // this should print only 9 and after that program should exit.
}
int main ()
{
    printNum( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `cout << num` is printed for *every* invocation of `printNum`. `printNum` is invoked, recursively, 9 times. That's why your second comment `this should print only 9...` is not entirely accurate. It will print `9` for `printNum(9)`, yes, but it will also print `8` afterwards for `printNum(8)`, etc...

After `printNum` ends, the program control is returned to the *previous* invocation of `printNum`. Thus, for example, after `printNum(9)` finishes, it returns to `printNum(8)` to print the second `8` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

What does `printNum(9)` print? Hopefully you can see that it outputs `99`, because the `if` is false.

So what does `printNum(8)` print? Well, `printNum` does three things in this case. First, it outputs `8`, that's the `cout << num ;` part. Then it outputs `99` (because that's what `printNum(num + 1)` will do if `num` is 8, see the first paragraph). Then it outputs `8`, since that's the next line of code. So `printNum(8)` will output `8998`.

So what does `printNum(7)` print? First `7`, then it calls `printNum(8)` which outputs `8998` (see the second paragraph). Then it outputs `7`. So `printNum(7)` will output `789987`.

Continue this analysis.

Comment: **Then it outputs 8, since that's the  next line of code** but why ? why will the program jump to last line if the **if statement** again calling printNum ? This should prevent the program to go to last line that says **cout<<num;**  !!!

Comment: When you call a function, what do you think happens when that function is done?

Comment: @PrakharShukla Remember that even `cout << num;` ends up calling functions. You're not surprised that `printNum` continues after `cout << num;` finished. Why is it surprising that `printNum` continues after a nested `printNum` finished?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When that function is done, the program exits ! explain me where i'm wrong or give me a link to read something more about recursion to clear my doubt please

Comment: @PrakharShukla If the program exited when a function was done, the program would exit as soon as `cout << num ;` executed, since that calls the `operator<<` function. (As hvd expained.) No, program flow continues where it left off after the function returns unless the function throws an exception or does something else very odd.

Comment: i've got it now. Thank you to all